# Problems with typing text using splinter

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, splinter

I want to type text, and send it like showed in the following link
[example of form to be filled out.](https://message.alibaba.com/msgsend/contact.htm?action=contact_action&appForm=s_en&chkCompanyIds=237608657&chkCompanyIds_f=IDX1DQMDYPAuROskCSZDE-LeENSEM6iXkieSkmMbHSZ7ym7_enhR28O_AzXCnw6cfHjg&tracelog=contactOrg)

I am however unable to type anything in the field. I supposed at first it was an iframe, but splinter is unable to locate it. If i search by tags for the body, it says that:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot focus element
```

How might i go about fixing this?

Answer (score 1):

if your element is not focused you have to first move to that element using selenium actions as following:

first move to  using ;

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#inquiry-content_ifr"))
```

Then focus on element

```
yourElement= driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".nav")

actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(menu)

actions.perform()
```

then do your interaction with that element after focus has been set to the element.

Comment: i get the following error:  selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"#inquiry-content_ifr"}

Comment: @sn3jd3r at which line?